# What colour is Legolas' hair?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

In the Lord of the Rings, no mention is made of Legolas' hair colour.

I think at the end of the Appendixes Tolkien stated (to the effect) " all the Eldar were dark except the Golden house of Finarfin"

Does this imply he had dark hair?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The evidence is fairly neatly summed up here: http://www.tolkiensociety.org/faq01.html#legolas

However, in Quendi and Eldar (HoME 11) we read the following:

> In general the Sindar appear to have very closely resembled the
>   Exiles, being dark-haired, strong and tall, but lithe. Indeed they
>   could hardly be told apart except by their eyes; for the eyes of
>   all the Elves that had dwelt in Aman impressed those of
>   Middle-earth by their piercing brightness.

But this should be considered indicative rather than conclusive, especially bearing in mind the points made in the Tolkien Society link, above.

In summary: we don't know and there are valid reasons to argue in favour of either fair or dark, so take your pick and form your own internal image.

Comment: I disagree strongly!  And during a spirited discussion with old @Richard have formulated a strong argument of my own.  It is given below.

Comment: @GemmanAster - much of your argument is based on falsehoods; Thingol *was* silver-haired and Thranduil *was* golden-haired, per my comments to your answer.

Comment: Come on @Darth old son!  In your reading of some equivocal evidence, in your opinion.. etc.  There are other readings and other opinions.

Comment: @GemmanAster - did you not read the quotes I gave in my comments to your answer?  There's no opinion there, it's what Tolkien wrote.

Comment: I did indeed @Darth!  But it is all a matter of how you interpret it.  Lets take the flies and spiders quote - on its face its hard to argue that Thranduil's hair is anything but blonde.  But I take it the 'gold' is the yellow flames cast on his SILVER hair.  That is how my understanding adapts to an equivocal situation - knowing Sindar are NOT blonde.  But.  The rest - no - I disagree with your reading and reasoning.  That doesn't mean we either need to have a 'ZOMG flamewarz!!!!' or even argue at all.  I think we are both pretty fanatical about Tolkien and are not going to budge anyway!!!